# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.Object)' method error occurs with nullable fields

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have an entity framework's EDMX generated class having a DOB (Date Of Birth) property.

```
public partial class Contact : EntityBase
{
    public Contact()
    {
    }

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DOB { get; set; }
}
```

I created a LINQ expression for searching records using a string value "2015-02-21" against DOB.

```
 Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> cntExpression = p => Convert.ToString(p.DOB).ToLower().Trim().Contains("2015-02-21");
```

I used business logic class's method to filter records using the above LINQ expression.

```
IQueryable<Contact> qryContact = _cntMgr.GetFiltered(cntExpression);
```

But as you can see that DOB is a nullable property, so it throws error when below code starts looping through records existing in the above IQueryable instance.

```
foreach (var contact in qryContact)
            {
                if (contact!=null)
                {
                    // some code gets execute here..
                }
            }
```

The error I get is this:

```
 LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

I already know that System.String ToString isn't supported in Linq to Entities, but I need a solution or a workaround for this problem.

Kindly help me in fixing this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why compare the date to a string, why not compare the date to a date?

Comment: Please post the implementation of `GetFiltered`. I just tested your query it does not throw an error.

Comment: Scott Chamberlain, the reason of comparing date to a string is that the actual class is also having some other properties like FirstName, LastName etc and the searched text can be a name or a date.

Answer (score 1):

Check for a null

```
Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> cntExpression = p =>
  p.DOB.HasValue 
  &&  Convert.ToString(p.DOB.Value).ToLower().Trim().Contains("2015-02-21");
```

An improvement would be to just compare the date component of the `DateTime`.

```
var want = new DateTime(2015, 2, 21);
Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> cntExpression = p =>
    p.DOB.HasValue && want == p.DOB.Value.Date;
```

Comment: If DOB is a `date` type or doesn't include a time component, you won't even need `.Date`

Comment: This question is about unsupported methods. Your answer only adds more unsupported methods.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you conversion is necessary, you can change your code to:

```
Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> cntExpression = p => p.DOB.HasValue && p.DOB.Value.ToShortDateString() == "2015-02-21";
```

Comment: Even *that* isn't necessary if DOB is a date type. A simple comparison to a DateTime object will work

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos, the actual class is having some other properties like FirstName, LastName etc and the searched can be a name or a date. So it's not a case when only date string will be sent for searching records.

Comment: Kamo, I get this error when I use your code:

 _LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToShortDateString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression_.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the expression to this will work !

```
Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> cntExpression = p => p.DOB.HasValue && p.DOB.Value.Year == Convert.ToInt32("2015") && p.DOB.Value.Month == Convert.ToInt32("02") && p.DOB.Value.Month == Convert.ToInt32("21");
```

Lemme know if you face any further issues on this.